# Type 'std::map<std::basic_string<char>, int>' is incomplete

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

Anywhere I try to use `std::map` with any variation of type parameters, I'm given the red syntax highlighting that should indicate a compiler error, but I'm still able to compile and run with no issues. I've restarted visual studio, cleaned my project, and rebuilt the project, yet the issue still persists. I've also tried deleting the `.sdf` as I thought it might be saving something weird in it's history, at least from what I've been researching it could have been the cause. I'm also on warning level 4; I've tried to lower it, but no juice.

[Syntax Highlighting Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaFON.png)

**Edit 1:**
It actually only seems to be an issue when part of a member function, if it is within a free function, I do not get any syntax highlighting.

**Edit 2:**

- **main.cpp**

  ```
  #include "MCVE.h"

  int main()
  {
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- **MCVE.cpp**

  ```
  #include "MCVE.h"
  #include <map>

  MCVE::MCVE()
  {
  }

  void MCVE::Test() const
  {
      // syntax highlighting error appears here
      std::map<std::string, int> myMap;
  }

  MCVE::~MCVE()
  {
  }
  ```
- **MCVE.h**

  ```
  #pragma once

  class MCVE
  {
  public:
      MCVE();
      void Test() const;
      ~MCVE();
  };
  ```

**Edit 3:** I've accepted Pete Becker's answer, but the issue seems to persist only on my local machine. I tagged this with Visual Studio because I assumed there was something wrong with it because it only has the highlighting issue on my home computer, and not my work computer.

**Final Edit:** The issue turned out to be that one of the headers that was included in the base type of the class I was having an issue with was using `header guards` instead of `pragma once` as was in the file I was working in. Adding the proper `#include` statements and explicitly stating the namespace on the functions did not resolve it. Only changing the `header guards` over to `pragma once` fixed the issue.

Comment: Where is `#include <string>`?

Comment: @Simple It is within a parent header file so I omitted it. Including it doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Do you have `using namespace std;` somewhere? Have you tried using `std::string` for the key type?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I do not have any `using namespace std;` anywhere within any files. I have also tried being explicit with `std::string`.

Comment: Post an MCVE or it never happened.

Comment: @juanchopanza I've included the link in **Edit 2:**

Comment: You need to put an MCVE *in the question*, not as a link.

Comment: @juanchopanza I've posted it in the question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new code is still missing `#include <string>`. The fact that the compiler doesn't complain about the name `std::string` only means that it's been declared somewhere; headers often use forward declarations for names that are defined elsewhere to avoid header bloat. That works fine, and is standard conforming, but you have to follow the discipline of having a `#include` directive for the appropriate header for **every** standard library type that you use.